# jQuery Selector for all descendants of a element

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors

I have a `<div id="rptViewer">` that has multiple div and tables, which in turn can have multiple div and tables.
I need a jQuery selector to select all the div or tables under "rptViewer" either directly or indirectly(nesting).

I am trying the following jQuery selectors.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("[id*='rptViewer'] table").each(function(i, item) {
             $(item).css('display', 'inline-block');
            });
            $("[id*='rptViewer'] div").each(function(i, item) {
                $(item).css('display', 'inline-block');
            });            

            $("[id*=rptViewer] table").attr("width","");
        });
    </script>
```

But when I am checking it using firebug, I found that only the direct child of 'rptViewer' are getting 'inline-block' CSS

Comment: `[id*='rptViewer'] div` should work. See this fiddle and check the output (3 `div` elements): http://jsfiddle.net/NYmpv/

Comment: in the demo I made works fine http://jsfiddle.net/v8tnR/

Comment: can you give us the HTML with it? If possible, use jsfiddle.net to show your problem, that would be easier to help you ;)

Comment: Why don't you simply use $("[id*='rptViewer'] table,[id*='rptViewer'] div").css('display', 'inline-block');?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you would like to include a class for all table and div inside of rptViewer.
You can do this way:

```
$("table, div", "#rptViewer").addClass('someStyle');
```

But if you would like to include a class only for real children of rptViewer.
You can do this way:

```
$("#rptViewer > table, #rptViewer > div").addClass('someStyle');
```

Comment: No need to use jQuery's each method in either case.  Just call addClass directly on either selector.

Comment: While this accepted answer might be true for the problem described, the headline of the question was different: "jQuery Selector for all descendants of a element". The answer to that is nowadays to just use the wildcard astericks selector $('element *').

Answer (score 2):

Instead of adding styles in JavaScript, add a style via CSS:

```
#rptViewer div,
#rptViewer table {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

---

You can use the `[id]` selector, and a comma separated list of selections:

```
$('#rptViewer div, #rptViewer table')...
```

If there are more elements you'd like to select, you might want to use `.find()`:

```
$('#rptViewer').find('div, table')...
```

---

Given that you're using `rptViewer` as an `[id]`, I'm going to assume you're using ASP.NET, in which case you should add a class to the element to simplify selection:

```
$('.viewer').find('div, table')...
```